# Mockgoose not intercepting db calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using mockgoose to mock the db in some controller unit tests. After running my test suite, I can find a user with the credentials in my test suite, in my database. I have a feeling it's got something to do with the fact that I'm connecting in app.js, but I'm lost.

Here's relevant code:

app.js:

```
var express       = require('express');
var path          = require('path');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var app           = express();
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var db;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://****:****@ds053438.mlab.com:53438/express-crud');
db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));

require('./router')(app);
```

router/controller:

```
var User        = require('../../models/user');
var routes = function(app) {
    var baseUrl = app.get('baseUrl') + '/users';

    /* POST new user */
    app.post(baseUrl + '/', function (req, res, next) {

        var user = new User();

        // FOR THE LOVE OF GOD HASH PASSWORD IDIOT
        user.password   = req.body.password;
        user.username   = req.body.username;
        user.admin      = false;

        User.create(user, function (err, createdUser) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'success',
                username: createdUser.username,
                success: true
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = routes;
```

model:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        trim: true
    },
    // hash it nerd.
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 12,
        trim: true
    },
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

tests:

```
var expect      = require('chai').expect;
var request     = require('supertest');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mockgoose   = require('mockgoose');

mockgoose(mongoose);

var app         = require('../../app.js');
var baseUrl     = app.get('baseUrl');

describe('CONTROLLERS', function() {
    describe('/users/', function () {

        describe('POST', function () {
            it('responds with 200 for valid payload', function (done) {
                request(app)
                .post(baseUrl + '/users')
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .send({
                    'username': 'testUserWithMockgoose',
                    'password': 'testPasswordThatsLongEnough'
                })
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }

                    done();
                })
            })
        });
    });
});
```

This isn't my complete code, but I tried to trim it down without losing any relevant info. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. `mockgoose(mongoose)`
 mock the mongoose after the app initialises and connect the mongoose. 

So it fails to mock the mongodb and CURD with your mongodb. 

what is your solution?

I am thinking if it is possible to separate `mongoose.connect` in another places, so it will call after the `mockgoose(mongoose).then()`